# How to optimize a SQL Query containing a max?

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

Please note that both T and T1 refer to same table.
We are trying to retrieve a maximum value and while retrieving max value, we
are interested in those rows, which have equal columnC values.

```
select * 
from table T
where T.columnA in (0,1,2,3)
  and T.columnB = (select max(T1.columnB)
                   from table T1
                   where T1.columnC = T.columnC)
```

Comment: What does that have to do with Hibernate? Removing the tag.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: postgres, DB2, Oracle - via hibernate.

Comment: **All** three of them? But I doubt you can convince your obfuscation layer (aka "ORM") to generate a different query.

Answer (score 1):

This type of query is typically more efficient using window functions:

```
select *
from (
  select *, 
         max(columnb) over (partition by columnc) as max_b
  from the_table 
  where columna in (0,1,2,3)
) t
where columnb = max_b;
```

If the condition on `columna` is very selective an index on that column would help. Some optimizers might generate more efficient plans if you change `columna in (0,1,2,3)` into `columna between 0 and 3`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about where do you want (which layer) the columnA filter, but maybe like this:

```
Select tt1.* from table tt1
inner join
(
    select * from 
        table  t1 
        inner join
        ( select max(T0.columnB) max_columnB
            from table t0 ) t2
            on t1.columnB = t2.max_columnB
) tt2 
on tt1.columnC = tt2.columnC
Where tt1.columnA in (0,1,2,3)
```

An index is needed for columnA, and columnB and for columnC to run fast.

Answer (score 0):

a_horse_sith_no_name is correct that window functions are generally a better approach.  Regardless of window functions or your query, indexes will help.

In particular, you want indexes on `T(columnc, columnb)` and `T(columnA)`.  That is two separate indexes.  The SQL optimizer should be able to take advantage of the indexes both for your query and for the window functions approach.